# How to remove a specific "system notification" in android?

Tags: android, notifications, system, screenshot

I'm want to remove the "system" screenshot notification. I already achieved it, using the Notification Listener Service and the ID which I got from my phone. But I found out that the ID for the system notification is changing on some samsung and other devices. How can I make sure to remove the notification also on other devices. is there a different way to detect that the system screenshot notification has shown? Some specific TAG?

Edit: This how I do it right now:

```
@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        //super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

        Log.i(TAG, "ID: " + sbn.getId());
        Log.i(TAG, "Package: " + sbn.getPackageName());

        //Remove Notification
        if (sbn.getId() == 2131820569) {
            if(status.getBoolean("comboserviceaktiv",false) || status.getBoolean("serviceaktiv",false) && standardprefs.getBoolean("settings_silent",false)){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    this.cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
                    Log.i(TAG, "System Screenshot Notification deleted");
                } else {
                    this.cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(),sbn.getTag(),sbn.getId());
                    Log.i(TAG, "System Sreenshot Notification deleted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds to me like security issue (that you managed to remove it even on your phone). You shouldn't be able to, visibility of notifications is user's choice, not app's (except it's own notifications of course, those can be hidden any time the app wish).

Comment: @Ped7g: But there is a method in the Notification Listener Service that allow you exactly this. I edited my post with the code I'm using right now. Many other apps are also doing things like this.